# AlertDialog Checkbox fragment

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

## I'm wondering to use AlertDialog in a Fragmente.Como extends class could make this code to work on a fragment class?

I'm having trouble using the fragments , still I do not understand how they work the fragment .

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.caseb.case_beauty_.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,
                container, false);
        Button btnVersao = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnEnviaSolicita);
        btnVersao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                List<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

                listItems.add("Item1");
                listItems.add("Item2");
                listItems.add("Item3");

                final CharSequence[] list = listItems.toArray(new CharSequence[listItems.size()]);


                View openDialog = (View) findViewById(R.id.openDialog);
                openDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        // Intialize  readable sequence of char values
                        final CharSequence[] dialogList = list;
                        final AlertDialog.Builder builderDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainFragment.this);
                        builderDialog.setTitle("Select Item");
                        int count = dialogList.length;
                        boolean[] is_checked = new boolean[count];

                        // Creating multiple selection by using setMutliChoiceItem method
                        builderDialog.setMultiChoiceItems(dialogList, is_checked,
                                new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int whichButton, boolean isChecked) {
                                    }
                                });

                        builderDialog.setPositiveButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                        ListView list = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
                                        // make selected item in the comma seprated string
                                        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                                        for (int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) {
                                            boolean checked = list.isItemChecked(i);

                                            if (checked) {
                                                if (stringBuilder.length() > 0) stringBuilder.append(",");
                                                stringBuilder.append(list.getItemAtPosition(i));


                                            }
                                        }

                        /*Check string builder is empty or not. If string builder is not empty.
                          It will display on the screen.
                         */
                                        if (stringBuilder.toString().trim().equals("")) {

                                            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Click here to open Dialog");
                                            stringBuilder.setLength(0);

                                        } else {

                                            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(stringBuilder);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                        builderDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Click here to open Dialog");
                                    }
                                });
                        AlertDialog alert = builderDialog.create();
                        alert.show();

                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is problem ? is it not showing  AlertDialog ?

Comment: Please write in english ...

Comment: android studio says it has this error:: "builder (android.content.context) in builder cannot be applied to Activity"

this line:

'final AlertDialog.Builder builderDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainFragment.this);'

Comment: sorry for my english

Comment: use `getActivity()` instead of `MainFragment.this`

Comment: does not work , this class is " Fragment " ... I can not implement this code in a " fragment "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 final AlertDialog.Builder builderDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainFragment.this);
```

to

```
 final AlertDialog.Builder builderDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

as it **AlertDialog.Builder** needs `Context`